# In c# is there a way to find and open a URL that exists without knowing the exact path?

Tags: c#, url

As part of a program I'm trying to have it open a URL that I know exists on the internet, but I don't know a portion of the path because it contains a unique identifier.

For example in the URL structure:

https://(I know this).com/(I know this)/(I only know one keyword that exists in here)

So essentially I need a method that finds a URL containing the parts and keyword I know, and fills in the rest of the path that I don't know.

Thanks!

Comment: Impossible; except for brute-forcing which is hopeless if the unknown part is more than a few characters

Comment: For sure, you can not achieve this. I think you have a more complex problem behind and you are trying to solve it in a wrong way.

Comment: This can only work if you _know_ the naming conventions used by the target domain or if you had previously crawled the entire site and indexed each url, even then you can't know every possible URL endpoint that the site has unless it has specifically published this information somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Despite everyone tells you it's impossible, there is a partial way around. Just use google.

For example, the link for this question is:

[In c# is there a way to find and open a URL that exists without knowing the exact path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63655178/in-c-sharp-is-there-a-way-to-find-and-open-a-url-that-exists-without-knowing-the)

The query I search:

```
site:(stackoverflow.com/questions/63655178 AND knowing)
```

The result is exactly [this](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&ei=2ORVX-S_DsHkgwe9kZPAAQ&q=site%3A%28stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F63655178+AND+knowing%29&oq=site%3A%28stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F63655178+AND+knowing%29&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQDDoECAAQR1CnCVj5DWCkO2gAcAF4AIABigSIAZMXkgEFNC00LjKYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjki5KZxtbrAhVB8uAKHb3IBBgQ4dUDCA0) question.

And if I specify query differently:

```
site:(stackoverflow.com/questions/63655178 AND not AND knowing)
```

I get [nothing in url, though content still match](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&ei=BuVVX-ytFrzVgweJ2InYDw&q=site%3A%28stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F63655178+AND+not+AND+knowing%29&oq=site%3A%28stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F63655178+AND+not+AND+knowing%29&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQDDoECAAQR1D9B1i7IGC2LWgAcAF4AIAB9AOIAaAekgEFNC03LjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjsyJGvxtbrAhW86uAKHQlsAvsQ4dUDCA0).

**Disclaimer**

This only works for public available links which crawled by google crawler (through special navigation files and/or plugins provided by site hosters).
Also, Google can filter some search results, based on region/law/site crawl frequency, so most of the time you probably find what you looking, but do not expect correctness at 100% and immediate result.

This also work in some other search engines, syntax differs, downsides pretty much same.

Comment: I must applaud your jedi skills, I hope I never need to use this, but it works really well.